# Can you have both a HTTP port and a TCP port exposed in AKS using Application Gateway?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

**Setup**:

- Azure Kubernetes Service
- Azure Application Gateway

We have kubernetes cluster in Azure which uses Application Gateway for managing network trafic. We are using appgw over Load Balancer because we need to handle trafic at layer 7, hence path-based http rules. We use kubernetes ingress controller for configuring appgw. See config below.

Now I want a service that both accept requests on HTTP (layer 7) and TCP (layer  4).

How do I do that? The exposed port should not be public on the big internet, but public on the azure network. Do I need to add another Ingress Controller that is not configured to use appgw?

This is what I want to accomplish:
[image]

This is the config for the ingress controller using appgw:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: service1
  labels:
    app: service1
  annotations:
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: /
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-private-ip: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      secretName: <somesecret>
  rules:
    - host: <somehost>
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /service1/*
            backend:
              serviceName: service1
              servicePort: http
```

Current setup:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you have two straightforward options.

---

Use direct pod IP or Headless ClusterIP Service.

I assume your AKS cluster employs either Azure CNI or Calico as a networking fabric.
In both cases **your Pods get routable ips in AKS subnet**.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-network#azure-cni-advanced-networking
Thus, you can make them accessible directly across your VNet.

---

Alternatively, you could use Service of type Internal Load Balancer.
You can build Internal LB thru appropriate annotations.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
```

*When you view the service details, the IP address of the internal load balancer is shown in the EXTERNAL-IP column. In this context, External is in relation to the external interface of the load balancer, not that it receives a public, external IP address.*
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb#create-an-internal-load-balancer

If needed, you can assign a predefined IP address to your LB and / or put it into a different subnet across your VNet or even into a private subnet, use VNet peering etc.
Eventually you can make it routable from wherever you need.

Comment: I went with having two Services for same pod; one for the HTTP handled by an Ingress (appgw) and one for TCP using Azure Load balancer as internal

Answer (score 1):

> The exposed port should not be public, but public in the kubernetes cluster.

I assume that you mean that your application should expose a port for clients within the Kubernetes cluster. You don't have to do any special in Kubernetes for Pods to do this, they can accept TCP connection to any port. But you may want to create a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) of `type: ClusterIP` for this, so it will be easer for clients.

Nothing more than that should be needed.

Comment: But is'nt ClusterIP only available within the cluster and not outside the cluster?

Comment: Wasn't that what you wanted? "should not be public". Please rephrase your question if this is not correct.

Comment: I have tried to update the question. Maybe it is just me who can't formulate the question right because I'm not sure what I'm doing ;)

Comment: This depends very much on how your network is setup and configured.

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging a Kubernetes Service should address your concern, all you need to do it modify your YAML file.

Leveraging a [Kubernetes Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) should address your concern, all you need to do it modify your YAML file.

Here is an example snippet where I have created a service

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: cafe-app-service
labels:
application: cafe-app-service
spec:
ports:

- port: 80
  protocol: HTTP
  targetPort: 8080
  name: coffee-port
- port: 8081
  protocol: TCP
  targetPort: 8081
  name: tea-port
  selector:
  application: cafe-app

You can reference your service in your ingress that you have created

Answer (score 0):

I went with having two Services for same pod; one for the HTTP handled by an Ingress (appgw) and one for TCP using an internal Azure Load balancer.

This is my config that I ended up using:

**ConfigMap**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-serviceA-cm
  namespace: default
data:
  8200: "default/serviceA:8200"
```

**TCP service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tcp-serviceA
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: serviceA
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: serviceA
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet: subnetA
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: tcp
      port: 8200
      targetPort: 8200
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: serviceA
    release: serviceA
```

**HTTP Ingress**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: serviceA
  labels:
    app: serviceA
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      secretName: <somesecret>
  rules:
    - host: <somehost>
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /serviceA/*
            backend:
              serviceName: serviceA
              servicePort: http
```

**Deployment**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: serviceA
  labels:
    app: serviceA
    release: serviceA
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: serviceA
      release: serviceA
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: serviceA
        release: serviceA
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: serviceA
          image: "serviceA:latest"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
```

**HTTP Service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: serviceA
  labels:
    app: serviceA
    release: serviceA
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app: serviceA
    release: serviceA
```